# Angular2 Authguard route to login

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

if user who don't login, want to go some secure root for example "/items" authguard return false and dont navigate "/login".

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: PublicComponent, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES},
  {
    path: '',
    component: SecureComponent,
    resolve: {user: UserResolver},
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: SECURE_ROUTES
  },
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

AuthGuard Code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
    let url: string = state.url;
    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
    this.userService.redirectUrl = url;
    return this.userService.getPrincipal()
      .map(user => {
        if(user)
          return true;

        return false;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here :) ?

Comment: if a user is not login then i want navigate login page? :)

Comment: @vangoo did you tried my code below ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `Router`, and redirect to login page if user is not logged in as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean{
    let url: string = state.url;
    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
    this.userService.redirectUrl = url;
    return this.userService.getPrincipal()
      .map(user => {
        if(user)
          return true;

        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: can authguard will be do navigate? is the best way?

Comment: Ofc you can redirect from Guard.

Comment: why will be return false after navigate?

Comment: To prevent access to the guarded state. (Redirect to accessible state, and cancel current navigation).